# draw polylines with different colors on v2 maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, rgb

I am drawing multiple polylines using for loop on version 2 google map. I am setting color to the polyline using the code.

```
mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(lats, lons), new LatLng(late,lone))
.width(5)
.color(0xFFFF0000));
```

How to increment the RGB color dynamically for each for loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Random rnd = new Random(); 
  int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));  
  --- loop ----

   mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
  .add(new LatLng(lats, lons), new LatLng(late,lone))
  .width(5)
  .color(color));
```