# Drawing different color polylines in android

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating an app which tracks user's location and draws a polyline when onLocationChange(Location location) is called. Polyline color depends on accelerometer. I know how to use polyline but PolyLineOptions object can be only one-color.
I read that it can be achieved by using a GroundOverlay however I don't have any idea how to use it and how to use my location when drawing a line on bitmap (don't know how to use it's coordinates). Can someone help me, give some example links? Please notice that each polyline (or bitmap line) should be added dynamically when user moves. I have done research but all I found is that [Drawing multi color PolyLines on Maps V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235237/drawing-multi-color-polylines-on-maps-v2) and it doesn't explains everything. Thanks for help!

Comment: When the user moves, can you then just create a new polyline with a set of points (that you can smooth out to minimize # of points) , instead of appending to your existing one? THis way, if you create a new polyline, then you can specify the color.

Comment: onLocationChange is called about every second so I think there will be to many polylines for processor to handle

Comment: Don't add right away. Collect them first, and for example, once the count reaches 1000 points (or a timer , every 5 minutes), SMOOTH it out first (to reduce the points) , then add a new polyline with those remaining points. If your user traveled in a straight line, then your smoothing algorithm should only retain 2 points.

Comment: But it's not what I want to do, because I want to draw single line on each locationChange and it's color depends on accelerometer change, and I want to do it in real time

Comment: @user1275995 were you ever able to solve your question? I'm facing something similar

Answer (score 0):

> "on each locationChange and it's color depends on accelerometer
>   change, and I want to do it in real time"

Note that this will probably make your app appear sluggish or hung whether you're adding a polyline or use the GroundOverlay approach that you wanted.

Anyway, here's how I would do it with the "GroundOverlay approach"

1.) Create *n* images that will represent each range of speed. For example red image for "slow" (0-1000), green image for 1001-2000, etc...)

2.) Define an array that will hold the resource id of these images, in order of how you want it to be. For example:

```
int[] speedImageBucket = {R.drawable.slow,R.drawable.medium,R.drawable.fast};
```

3.) So everytime locationChange fires, compute which image to add, and add to the map as overlay. Example:

```
....
float speed = loc.getSpeed(); // loc is the current location object passed in
int speedBucket = (int) (speed / 1000); // 1000 is the linear increment of your ranges for example

 //TODO: handle if speedBucket (array index) is out of range

 GoogleMap map = ...; // get a map.
 BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(speedImageBucket[speedBucket ]);; // get an image.

 // Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency.
 GroundOverlay groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
 .image(image)
 .position(loc,1)
 .transparency(0.5));
```

Comment: OK, but tell me how to estimate start and end of the line, it's width can't be fixed it should depend on accelerometer data so it has to be flexible, I can't just add static images.