# Multi color Polyline in google map v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I searched a lot i didn't find any proper solution for it.Help and link could be appreciated :-)[image: multicolored polyine]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/q/22235237/1840795

Comment: @NakulSudhakar i tried its it will not help

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758825/dynamic-polyline-colors-with-google-maps-android-app/35789936#35789936

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417530/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 2):

maybe its so late !!! but i solve this problem and want put it for some people. maybe useful. and for detail i solve it by new polylineOption every 5 Latlng in map

```
 private static void animateMarker(final GoogleMap map, final Marker marker, final List<LatLng> directionPoint,
                                  final boolean hideMarker, final List<Float> degree, final List<Integer> colors) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final long duration = 300000;
    final PolylineOptions[] polylineOptions = {new PolylineOptions()};
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    if (map != null) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                if (i < directionPoint.size() - 1) {

                    final LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(
                            directionPoint.get(i).latitude * (1 - t) + directionPoint.get(i + 1).latitude * t,
                            directionPoint.get(i).longitude * (1 - t) + directionPoint.get(i + 1).longitude * t);

                    marker.setRotation(degree.get(i));
                    marker.setPosition(currentPosition);
                    polylineOptions[0].add(directionPoint.get(i)).color(colors.get(i));
                    map.addPolyline(polylineOptions[0]);
                    if (i % 5 != 0) {
                        polylineOptions[0] = new PolylineOptions();
                        polylineOptions[0].add(directionPoint.get(i)).color(colors.get(i));
                        map.addPolyline(polylineOptions[0]);
                    }
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition);
                    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    i++;

                }
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 100ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Ok it's my screenshot , color will be change by changing speed of car

Comment: share your screenshot it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  -

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Add a thin red line from A to B.
    Polyline line1 = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(40.1, -74.2), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
        .width(5)
        .color(Color.RED));
```

and then another line from B to C with a different color and so on

```
Polyline line2 = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(40.7, -74.0), new LatLng(41.3, -74.5))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.GREEN));
 ....
```

Note that getMapAsync() is the new preferred way to get the map object.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map

Polyline details here - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

Comment: thanks its good answer .But its not working still if i create a multiple instance of polylineOptions with different color my google map shows only one color at the final in android

Answer (score 0):

You could see this results in separated polylines.
This could be improved by adding round start caps and round end caps of each polylines.

```
polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
polyline2.setStartCap(new RoundCap());
```