# Route draw between three points with different color in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-maps-markers

I want to create route between three point like A, B, C.

I want to show red route color between A and B.
I want to show green route color between B and C.

I am using below google api for draw point on map.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=21.232528%2C72.869113&destination=22.317793%2C73.180586&waypoints=via:21.705930,72.993247&key=AIzaSyDU10EC_MeQYUSsTVNTUrBdgxiB688zEQk

Please check my snapshot of google map with points.[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417530/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Plot points one by one then you can easily change polyline color accordingly.