# How to make a multicolored overview polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I have added an overview polyline in my map but now I want it look multicolored on different latitudes and longitudes.
If you can please help me find how to get through this problem I will be grateful

```
public void User(final Context context,final GoogleMap gMap) {

    Log.d("seee",makeURL());

    final MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, makeURL(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
List<LatLng> startLatLng=null;
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
             JSONObject json=null;


            try {


                json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
                for(int i=0;i<routeArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray rAQI=routeArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
                     startLatLng=getLatitudeLongitudes(rAQI);

                    JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                            .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                    String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
                    List<LatLng> list = PolyUtil.decode(encodedString);
                    if(i!=0) {
                        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(17).color(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorGreyline)).geodesic(true);
                        for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
                            LatLng point = list.get(z);
                            options.add(point);
                        }
                        gMap.addPolyline(options);
                        options.clickable(true);

                    }
                    else {
                        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(20).color(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorBlueline)).geodesic(true);
                        for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
                            LatLng point = list.get(z);
                            options.add(point);
                        }
                        gMap.addPolyline(options);
                        options.clickable(true);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+startLatLng.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

I want to get something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ0kp.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880472/multi-color-polyline-in-google-map-v2-in-android and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235237/drawing-multi-color-polylines-on-maps-v2 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47417530/7666442

Comment: they haven't used overview polyline.I want to make changes on the overview polyline @NileshRathod